# Marklogic SQL93 and date comparisons

Tags: sql, date, marklogic

Marklogic has SQL92 standard built in and the documentation in MakLogic has some details on Date Function

I have a simple query to compare a date to a string date passed in. But there seems no way to convert a string to a date inline with MarkLogic implementation of SQL92.

I have looked at the standard function and they have a curdate but no equivalent to CAST or CONVERT nor will curdate take an argument.

```
select dateStart from namespace.dateTable
where coalesce(dateStart,curdate())> XXX('1 Nov 2019')
```

I want to return all dates after 1st of Nov 2019 in this case

Comment: `curdate()` isn't standard SQL to begin with. In standard SQL, you would write `coalesce(datestart, current_date) > date '2019-11-01'`. Additionally: there is no SQL93 standard. It's either SQL-92 or SQL:1999

Comment: You may have missed the whole MarkLogic thing.  Thiss is their implementation of sql.

Comment: So what is this SQL93 standard supposed to be then? Some MarcLogic specific "standard"?

Comment: I appoligise it is SQL92 but the rest remains true as the https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries

Comment: As I wrote: in standard SQL that would be: `coalesce(datestart, current_date) > date '2019-11-01'` - but I don't know MarcLogic, so I don't know if they really comply with that

Comment: Yes that worked

Answer (score 1):

Need to utilise Binding. Thanks to the web site [Avalon](http://blogs.avalonconsult.com/blog/marklogic-2/marklogic-9-introduces-row-oriented-views-and-the-optic-api/).

```
const minYear = xs.date('2019-11-01');

//create a binding with the date being passed as a date
var bindings = {"date": minYear};

//add to the SQL the variable @date
var sqlString = `select * from namespace.table 
where dateStart >= @date limit 100
`;

//execute the sql with third argument the binding
xdmp.sql(sqlString, null, bindings).toArray();
```